# How to set cmake parameter CMAKE_MODULE_PATH in Yocto project recipe?

Tags: cmake, yocto

I need to set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` for my recipe. How do you set it correctly? How can I add a path to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` before calling `cmake`?

Comment: Can you provide some context as to *why* you want to modify this variable prior to calling `cmake`? Are you going to be using it for calling other modules with `include()`? Or are you using it with `find_package()`?

Comment: Documentation for the [CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) variable states, that "it is intended to be set by the **project**". So it is rarely a good intention to set this variable in the `cmake` command line.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can set the [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) from the command line like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/path/to/your/local/modules ..
```

However, if using this for [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), I suggest checking out the documentation for how this will affect the `find_package()` behavior. Depending on your project setup, you may not want to universally add this path to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`; so it may be best to set an intermediate variable instead, and use the intermediate variable to update `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` only in certain cases.